# Addfontfeatures not working after update

Tags: fonts, luatex, fontspec

I have updated my LaTeX recently and I am getting error when using `\addfontfeatures`

Here is my MWE (you can use any font)

```
 \documentclass{article}

\usepackage{polyglossia}

\setmainlanguage{english}

\setmainfont{MetaSerifPro-}[
    Extension = .otf,
    UprightFont = MetaSerifPro-Book,
    ItalicFont = MetaSerifPro-BookItalic,
    BoldFont = MetaSerifPro-Bold,
    BoldItalicFont = MetaSerifPro-BoldItalic,
%    Numbers = Uppercase
]


\begin{document}

    \addfontfeatures{Numbers = Uppercase}

    Hello 123

\end{document}
```

I get an error

```
luaotfload | aux : font no 34 (nil) defines no feature for script latn with lang
uage eng...texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luaotfload/luaotfload-features.lua:252: bad arg
ument #1 to 'stringgsub' (string expected, got boolean).
<to be read again> 
\scan_stop: 
l.20    \addfontfeature{Numbers = Uppercase}

? 
! Emergency stop.
<to be read again> 
\scan_stop: 
l.20    \addfontfeature{Numbers = Uppercase}
```

However if I uncomment `Numbers = Uppercase` in the preamble and comment out `\addfontfeature` line, everything works. I am getting this error with every font I try, so it seems that the porblem is with `fontspec`.

I use LuaLaTeX.

**UPD:** it seems that the bug has been fixed in the latest patch of `fontspec` (2.7f)

Comment: See https://github.com/wspr/fontspec/issues/403

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Update

fontspec 2020/01/26 v2.7g has resolved the problem. The work around is no longer needed

===================

You could try this work-around. It perhaps will set the language or the script wrong, but you could correct this then in the font declaration:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{polyglossia}

\setmainlanguage{english}

\setmainfont{TeXGyreHeros}[
     Numbers = Uppercase
]
\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_set:Nn \l__fontspec_pre_feat_sclist
  {
    mode     = \l__fontspec_mode_tl   ;
    \tl_if_empty:NF \l__fontspec_shaper_tl
      {
        shaper = \l__fontspec_shaper_tl   ;
      }
    \tl_if_empty:NF \l__fontspec_script_tl
      {
        script   = \l__fontspec_script_tl ;
      }
    \tl_if_empty:NF \l__fontspec_lang_tl
     {
       language = \l__fontspec_lang_tl   ;
     }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

    \addfontfeatures{Numbers = Uppercase}

    Hello 123

\end{document}
```

Comment: Trying to compile OPs code gives `bad argument #1 to 'stringgsub' (string expected, got boolean).` again, on MiKTeX with `fontspec` version `2.7i` (so newer than `g`) and luatex `1.11.2`.

Comment: @HansLollo Works fine for me. But my miktex has a newer luatex. Check also your luaotfload version.